# AWS Lambda EFS | EACCES: permission denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-efs

So, I am trying to integrate my lambda function with EFS. I am able to access the root directory (as read-only from lambda) as I can see `xyz` directory available in my root dir. `/mnt/` -> `xyz`

When I try to access `/mnt/xyz` or `/mnt/xyz/` then I get this error:

```
{
  "errorType": "Error",
  "errorMessage": "EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/mnt/xyz/'",
  "trace": [
    "Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/mnt/xyz/'",
    "    at Object.readdirSync (fs.js:948:3)",
    "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:19:24)",
    "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
  ]
}
```

Permission given to the access point: 777

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I tried to **replicate** the issue, and can verify that I had the same problem. The help came from the following GitHub issue: [EFS permission denied](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/1631).

The permission denied was caused by incorrectly set root and local mount point in the access point and lambda respectively. The correct setting that **worked** were:

#### Access point (note `/lambda`)

[image]

#### Lambda (note `/mnt/lambda`)

[image]

These settings enable successful access to the EFS.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Though, this is not what happened in my case as I was able to access the root dir (print `xyz` dir [sub dir inside efs] in lambda console). It surprisingly turned out to be a user/group id issue.

Comment: @NishantThapliyal Thanks for letting me know. Glad it worked out eventually :-)

Comment: I had the exact issue you described. Thanks @Marcin

Comment: @NishantThapliyal how did you resolve the user/groupid issue?

Comment: @Paulo I've posted a detailed answer below.

Answer (score 23):

The issue that I was facing was related to the user/group id (ownership). The file was produced by an application running on AWS EC2 instance and consumed by AWS Lambda function.

To find the owner/group of files use cmd `ls -al`

[image]

To find the owner/group **IDs** use cmd `ls -n`

[image]

As the file produced by the root (UID: 0) I need to set the `owner id` and `group id` as `0` at EFS access point

[image]

This configuration resolved my issue.

Comment: I just ran the `ls -l` commands (temporarily) in a lambda itself to ensure that it could see the EFS. I also had to combine this with poking a port hole (2049, both in and out) into a security group, so that the EFS-to-lambda file traffic can get through. Thanks for your post.

Comment: After looking through dozens of posts and articles and every relevant AWS doc on the subject and absolutely nothing working, this resolved my write permission error for a Lambda trying to simply test writing a .txt file to EFS. All I had to do was change the user/owner IDs to 0. Thank you so much, it's absolutely ludicrous that this is opaque in the  documentation.

Comment: +1 for setting UID GID to 0. 1000 never worked for my case, which I doubt it was due to my lambda was a docker layered lambda. I have not tried a native Lambda write with 1000.